# Microsecond precision for DMS CDC with DB2 as source EndPoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, db2, cdc, aws-dms

I am using **DB2** as a source endpoint and replicating data into Amazon **S3** through Amazon **DMS CDC**  task.
I want to track all operations so I have added a column "dms_timestamp" using TimestampColumnName property along with parquetTimestampInMillisecond as True.

But I am not getting time in microseconds for CDC.
I know CDC timestamp depends on Source transaction timestamp but I can confirm DB2 has microsecond precision.

I have multiple cases where data getting update within a millisecond and I want to capture the latest change only. Consider there is no Watermark column of a table.

I have tried all transformation with AR_* But it did not help.

***Please help me to get a timestamp with microSeconds precision.***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In environments that support microsecond precision, the date and time format of &TIMSTAMP journal control field is `YYYY-MM-DDHH:MM:SS.UUUUUU`. Identifies the date and time of when the insert, update, or delete operation or refresh was made on the source.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/refs/recordmodificationtime.html